# Closest cluster distance (No centroid)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am interested in finding the distribution of nearest neighbor cluster distance in a spatial data set (lon, lat). My cluster criteria is simple, meaning that when two points are next to each other they belong to the same cluster and the minimum number of points in a cluster is one. To do so I am using sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN. After clustering, I want to find the distance to the closest cluster for each cluster and that's where I am having problems. Everything I have found calculates the nearest neighbor distance between the **centroids** of the clusters, and I want to use the **boundaries** instead.

[image: Instead finding the blue distance, I want to find the black.]

At the moment I am doing so by taking all the points from one cluster, then calculating the distance of every point of this cluster with all the points of the remaining clusters and finally taking the minimum distance. However, as you can imagine this is very inefficient and the calculation takes forever.

Does anyone knows how to properly do this?

Comment: I think you might be interested in convex hull algorithms. Such algorithms will allow you to draw a boundary shape around your clusters. That boundary shape should be a polygon that you can get all the vertices of. Calculate the distance between your point and all of those vertices and find the two vertices with the two smallest distances between that point. Those two vertices make a line and you can find the (perpendicular) distance between your point and that line.

Answer (score 0):

Use the nearesr-neighbor classifier.

But in *all* points, not the cluster centers!

Sklearn has utility functions that can make finding the nearest neighbor faster than computing all distances, for example using a kd-tree.